# How to add a contact without a name in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I have a collection of contact info that I would like to add to Google Contacts via the ContactsApp. Is some cases this info is just an e-mail address without a name.

```
contact = ContactsApp.createContact("tmp1", "tmp2", "email");
```

The above doesn't seem to accept "" as an argument. Neither do the following:

```
contact.setGivenName(".");
contact.setFamilyName(":");
contact.setFullName("*");
```

I could use " ", but that is not ideal. Is there any way to have the names be "" just like when an e-mail address is saved from a gmail message sent without the name being available?

Comment: You _can_ import contacts with email-only, so why not just use Google's UI? If you feel you must use a script, you could import a group of 'template' contacts with no name, then use `.getContactsByGroup('template')` to grab a template contact and modify the relevant fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use null

```
contact= ContactsApp.createContact(null,null,"email@somewhere.com");
```